# Mallet: Alphabets don't match, exception when making model again in one program

Tags: java, mallet

I have explored mallet and it is working good. What I am trying to do is making a model twice in a program scope and facing exception. My program code is as:

```
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("--input input.mallet --output-classifier output_classifier.classifier --trainer MaxEnt --report train:accuracy");

commands.add("--input input.mallet --output-classifier output_classifier.classifier --trainer MaxEnt --report train:accuracy");

for( int index = 0; index < commands.size(); index++ ) {
    try {
        Vectors2Classify.main(commands.get(index).split(" "));
    } catch (EvalError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

First one command is running successfully. On second command I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alphabets don't match: Instance: [9327, 3], InstanceList: [9327, 3]

    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.add(InstanceList.java:335)
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.shallowClone(InstanceList.java:213)
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.split(InstanceList.java:513)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify.main(Vectors2Classify.java:397)
```

I have searched this problem but did not found any solution till now. It look like that no one have tried until now making a model twice in a program scope.
If anyone can help me on this, will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function is designed to be called once within a program execution. There is probably some variable that is being carried over from one invocation to the next. There is a lot of logic in this `Vectors2Classify` for figuring out user intention from command line arguments. If you need to write Java code, copying code from `Vectors2Classify` to do exactly what you want is probably a better option.